# Gradle task - copy from resolved configuration

Tags: gradle, groovy, build, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have following task:

```
task copySomething(type: Copy) {
  dependsOn configurations.myConf
  into "build/something"
  from(zipTree(configurations.myConf.asPath)) {
    include "*.sql"
  }
}
```

It works but it causes configuration `myConf` to be resolved during configuration phase, which makes it impossible to add more dependencies to configuration `myConf` further in the build.gradle (it causes error: `Cannot change dependencies of dependency configuration ':my-project:myConf' after it has been resolved.`).

How can I create a task which simply copies configuration without resolving that configuration in the "configuration phase" of Gradle build (it should resolve it in the "execution phase")?

Also - what is the effect of `dependsOn configurations.myConf`? It does not resolve the configuration before the task is executed, from what I experienced it has really no effect.

Comment: I tried moving `from(zipTree(configurations.myConf.asPath)) ` to the `doLast` section - but it does not work

Comment: Does `from(configurations.named("myConf").map { it.asPath })` work?